# GetObject function returns "default" value for LOGFONT argument. What am I missing?

Tags: visual-c++

I am using VS2019 Community on a 64-bit laptop running Windows 11.

I have researched a number of online suggestions for adjusting the property values of an HFONT object with limited success.  My goal is to implement a generic function to adjust font size.

To that end, I have written the following source code:
`
//==============================================================================
#include "stdafx.h"
//X #include <ocidl.h>   // PATH is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\ocidl.h

```
//==============================================================================
// Function ScaleFont().  
//==============================================================================
HFONT ScaleFont(
    HFONT hFont
  , HWND  hWnd
  , double PctAdjustmentSPEC
  )
{
  double PctAdjustment    = min(max(PctAdjustmentSPEC,0.875),1.125);
  LOGFONT lf;
  int NumBytes = GetObject((HGDIOBJ)hFont,sizeof(lf),(void*)(&lf));
  double WidthHeightRatio = double(lf.lfWidth)/double(lf.lfHeight);
  lf.lfHeight = LONG(floor(lf.lfHeight * PctAdjustment));
  lf.lfWidth  = LONG(floor(lf.lfWidth * PctAdjustment * WidthHeightRatio));
  HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
  DeleteObject((HGDIOBJ)hFont);
  hFont = (HFONT)CreateFontIndirect(&lf);  
  SelectObject(hdc,hFont);
  ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
  return hFont;
}
```

The problem is with the 3rd line,
int NumBytes = GetObject((HGDIOBJ)hFont,sizeof(lf),(void*)(&lf));
which returns NumBytes==0 and a LOGFONT object all of whose values == -MAXINT.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for attending to this.
Bard of Chelsea

In my various attempts,
(1)   I tried using IFont methods but couldn't compile.
(2)   I tried substituting HANDLE for HGDIOBJ, which compiles.
(3)   I tried using GetLogicalFont in lieu of GetObject per one online article, but VS2019 didn't recognize GetLogicalFont as a function name.

Comment: Most likely, `hFont` passed to the function is not a valid font handle. The problem might be in the calling code, not shown.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik   Caller source: 

    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) 

    { 

      static HFONT hFont; 

              .. 

        WM_CREATE 

              .. 

          hFont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(ANSI_FIXED_FONT); 

              .. 

        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:  

        { 

          if (pFmtdText != NULL) 

          { 

            WheelDelta = -GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam)/120; 

            if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)) 

            { 

              hFont = ScaleFont(hFont,hWnd,1.0 - 0.03125 * WheelDelta);

Comment: Does it fail on the very first call of `ScaleFont`, or on some subsequent calls? You do some very weird stuff with `SelectObject(hdc,hFont); ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);` - I suspect the font might get destroyed when the `HDC` it's selected into is released. In any case, these two calls make no sense. It's not clear why you need to muck about with `HWND` or `HDC` at all in this function.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik My bad.  You were correct.   hFont argument == NULL on first call to ScaleFont() due to coding error in Caller.